# Why webview_flutter not working in case of add to app (iOS)?

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-ios, webview-flutter, flutter-add-to-app

So I am trying to open a simple webview when a button is clicked.

This is the body of my Scaffold widget:

```
body: 
WebView(
    initialUrl: "https://www.google.com/",
    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
)
```

The interesting part is when I run this flutter project independently it successfully opens the Webview in the iOS simulator. **But when I integrated this flutter module into an existing iOS App it doesn't work** (Shows a blank screen). In order to add a flutter module, I have followed this [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/ios/project-setup), the other part of the module works fine.

I have already set this in the info.plist for the flutter module:

```
<key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
<true/>
```

I have added the following version in `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
webview_flutter: ^0.3.22+1
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few hours of debugging I found that **we need to add this key in the iOS project `info.plist` file rather than putting it into the info.plist in the iOS folder of the flutter module**

```
<key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
<true/>
```

Answer (score 8):

Ive ran into this issue too when using [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter). Fortunately, the ios setup from [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) seemed to work.  I used this tag in xcode's Info.list:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 1):

If url you're using has some special character. So,You need to encode the URL like this,

```js
 WebView(
      initialUrl: Uri.encodeFull(yourUrl),
      ...
 )
```